# How to send email with Freemarker template in Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, html-email, freemarker

I am trying to send email with Freemarker template.

Code:

```
public String geContentFromTemplate(Map<String, Object> model) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        fmConfiguration.getTemplate("email-template.ftlh").process(model, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
}

public void sendEmailWithTemplate(String to, String subject, User user) {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {

            MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(emailFrom);
            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(to);
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
            model.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
            String content = geContentFromTemplate(model);
            mimeMessageHelper.setText(content, true);

            mailSender.send(mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException | IOException | TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Freemarker Bean:

```
 @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean getFreeMarkerConfiguration() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean fmConfigFactoryBean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
        fmConfigFactoryBean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:templates/email-template.ftlh");
        return fmConfigFactoryBean;
    }
```

My template is located in Spring Boot application: `resources/templates/email-template.ftlh`

I receive this exception:
`freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "email-template.ftlh". The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader@33cceeb3.`

Comment: It is based on the spring resource system, so I think the path in the code should be something like `classpath:templates/email-template.ftlh`. Assuming by 'resources' you mean src/main/resources.

Comment: @Gimby Getting the same error: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "classpath:templates/email-template.ftlh"
I have added my Freemarker Bean to post

Comment: yeah, so that setTemplateLoaderPath would then probably be classpath:templates

Comment: No feedback for several days. Was that the solution or did you fix it in another way?

Comment: @Gimby Sorry for late feedback. I still have same problem.(Updated setTemplateLoarderPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that by changing @Bean. I removed previous one and created another:

```
  @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer(){
        freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = new freemarker.template.Configuration(freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_19);
        TemplateLoader templateLoader = new ClassTemplateLoader(this.getClass(), "/templates/");
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setConfiguration(configuration);
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
```

Also template loading implemented like that:

```
            Template template = freeMarkerConfigurer.getConfiguration().getTemplate("email-template.ftlh");
            String htmlBody = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, model);
```